# Google Play Privacy Warning: Not adhering to Families Policy Requirements policy

Tags: android, policy, privacy

**Email content:**
Violation:
Not adhering to Families Policy Requirements policy
Details:
Your app does not adhere to the following Google Play Developer Program policies:
Families Policy Requirements
Designed for Families Program Requirements

Issue with your app
We found the following issue(s) with your app:
Your app contains ads that don’t comply with our Families ad format requirements. For example, we don’t allow:
Ads or offers for in-app purchases that aren’t clearly distinguishable from your app content. For example, your app contains an ad that isn’t clearly labeled, or your app contains an ad that’s stylistically similar to the game interface.
To resolve this issue, remove any violating ad content before submitting an app update. Make sure your app uses a version of the Families Self-Certified Ads SDKs listed in the program. For details, refer to the “Format requirements” section of the Families Ads and Monetization policy.

**Question:**
[attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ne7Nd.png)
Also see the attached image, in the image on the left side; main menu of the game, in the middle; promotion banners of other games and on the right side; Google Play page that opens when you click one of the banners. On top of the promotional banners, there are 2 buttons Subscribe and Close buttons. Subscribe button is to subscribe to promotional mail and the close button closes that page. There is nothing else on the page.

They attached this image with the above description.

The app targets +13 ages and answered yes to the question "Could your store listing unintentionally appeal to children?".

Can anyone help me with the problem please? Let me know if I forgot to add anything.

I tried changing the promotional text to “Clicking on the banner ads below will take you directly to the store page” to make it more clear that those are banner ads that takes user to store. But it didn't solve the problem.

**Update:**
Tried to disable the page altogether, but it doesn't seem to be triggering review process for the privacy stuff. Do I need to do something to trigger that process? I'm just publishing the build on internal release and production.

Comment: Along with using `Clicking on the banner ads below will take you directly to the store page`, use an `Ad` tag as well ( (usually it is white text & yellowish background) somewhere on the cards as well to distinguish that they are actually promotional contents & not exactly part of your app content. I am assuming that the Ad SDKs used in the app (if any) adhere to said policies.

Comment: @Darshan Tried to disable the page altogether, but it doesn't seem to be triggering review process for the privacy stuff. Do I need to do something to trigger that process? I'm just publishing the build on internal release and production.